# Samba Configuration on RHEL 8.2: SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, samba, redhat-enterprise-linux

I've been taking a crack at configuring Samba to allow my Guest OS (RHEL 8.2), running on Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.1.8, to talk to my Host OS (Win10) following this guide [here](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Sharing_Files_between_RHEL_and_Windows_Systems_with_Samba). Unfortunately, using a Shared Folder via Guest Additions does not provide the dev environment that is required.

So upon running:
`# smbclient -U {myuser} -L localhost`
I get the following:

```
Enter WORKGROUP\{myuser}'s password: 

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    athena          Disk      ATHENA Server              # my desired share, mapped to root
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Samba 4.11.2)
    {myuser}        Disk      Home Directories
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available
```

I believe that this error: `SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available` is blocking my Host OS' ability to detect the share on the network via the VM Box's IP

So far my google-fu has turned up no pertinent results, so any insights would be appreciated

Relevant Configuration Info (What I think is at least):
**testparm** *Passes*

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
```

**smb.conf**

```
# See smb.conf.example for a more detailed config file or
# read the smb.conf manpage.
# Run 'testparm' to verify the config is correct after
# you modified it.

[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    protocol = SMB3
    security = user
    map to guest = bad user
    guest ok = yes
    netbios name = athena_server
    passdb backend = tdbsam

    log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
    log level = 1

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = no
    read only = no
    inherit acls = yes

[athena]
    comment = ATHENA Server
    path = /
    valid users = {myuser}
    browseable = yes
    public = yes
    writable = yes

#[printers]
#   comment = All Printers
#   path = /var/tmp
#   printable = Yes
#   create mask = 0600
#   browseable = No

#[print$]
#   comment = Printer Drivers
#   path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
#   write list = @printadmin root
#   force group = @printadmin
#   create mask = 0664
#   directory mask = 0775
```

**sestatus**

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

**semanage boolean -l | grep samba**

```
samba_create_home_dirs         (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to create home dirs
samba_domain_controller        (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to domain controller
samba_enable_home_dirs         (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to enable home dirs
samba_export_all_ro            (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to export all ro
samba_export_all_rw            (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to export all rw
samba_load_libgfapi            (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to load libgfapi
samba_portmapper               (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to portmapper
samba_run_unconfined           (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to run unconfined
samba_share_fusefs             (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to share fusefs
samba_share_nfs                (on   ,   on)  Allow samba to share nfs
sanlock_use_samba              (on   ,   on)  Allow sanlock to use samba
tmpreaper_use_samba            (on   ,   on)  Allow tmpreaper to use samba
use_samba_home_dirs            (on   ,   on)  Allow use to samba home dirs
virt_use_samba                 (on   ,   on)  Allow virt to use samba
```

Answer (score 4):

It isn't an error, it is a fact. You have 'protocol = SMB3' , which is actually 'server max protocol = SMB3', which is the default, so you don't need it. There is also a default setting of 'server min protocol = SMB2_02', which means that SMBv1 is turned off and you need SMBv1 for network browsing. Because this is Linux, you have two options, browse to the share via UNC or set up Avahi on both machines